# How to enable css property when other css property was enabled?

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox-3

Is it possible to enable css property when other css roperty was enabled by fancybox plugin?

Here is what I mean. When the **zoom icon** got pressed the `cursor` property was changed to `grab`. So is it possible to enable `image-rendering` property when that happened?

[image]

Comment: You could try a good ole fashioned `!important`, copy their CSS selectors for the cursor grab and include `image-rendering:pixelated !important`

Comment: @imvain2 perfect

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

In your case, assuming that there's already a style in place like

.FancyboxStyle {
...
}

What you can do is

.FancyboxStyle.MyStyle {
... // add css properties here
}

Now, if the element has both the FancyboxStyle and Myself, it will add the styles you specified